# get a response from another API while FutureBuilder works

Tags: flutter, dart

```
late Future<Kategori> _futureArticles;
late Future<Article> _futureSummary;
```

and the API's

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _futureArticles = _newsService.getArticlesByCategory(widget.id);
    _futureSummary = _newsService.getArticleById(widget.id);
    super.initState();
  }
```

and FutureBuilder

```
child: FutureBuilder<Kategori>(
          future: _futureArticles,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Kategori> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final articles = snapshot.data?.data;
```

now with FutureArticles and with this structure everything works but I need an another json value from _futureSummary. Both API's has got same ID values, so I can get the json.summary value from second API. But how? I tried to use future.wait but it did not work.

Meanwhile I am using second APi on different page to get all informations of a spesific news.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want your Future builder to rebuild only when both futures completed? If so - try to combine both futures. Future.wait will wait for all Future objects you pass to complete, and return List of results:

Let me update my answer with the working demo - you can test it in DartPad. Note that the first Future will complete after 1 second (and write the log in the console), but the FutureBuilder will wait until the second Future is completed, and only then show the values from both.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
 
  late Future<String> _futureArticles;
  late Future<int> _futureSummary;
  
  
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _futureArticles = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:1), () {print("First is done"); return "First is done";});
    _futureSummary = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:5), () => 10);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: Future.wait([_futureArticles, _futureSummary]),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final articles = snapshot.data![0] as String;
              final summary= snapshot.data![1] as int;
              
              return Column(children:[
                Text(articles),
                Text('$summary')
              ]);
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  ```The argument type 'StatelessWidget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<Kategori>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable```

Comment: Try to change this ````builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Kategori> snapshot)```` to this ````builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot)````